# WebClient support for application/xml in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring

I am upgrading from Spring Boot version 2.7.2 to version 3, the `WebClient` configured with `@Configuration` is throwing content type not supported exception during implementation. Does it require anything different to process `application/xml` for WebClient in Spring Boot 3 since the javax dependencies are replaced with jakarta? I have the following jaxb jars available as dependencies.

- jaxb-core - 2.2.11
- jaxb-impl - 2.2.11
- jaxb-runtime - 2.3.6
- jaxb-api - 2.3.1

Configuration:

```
public WebClient getWebClient(String url) {

    WebClient webClient = null;
    try {
        webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url)
                .defaultHeaders(headers -> {
                    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,                                      MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
                    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
                    headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
                })
                .exchangeStrategies(
                    ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                    .codecs( configurer -> 
                        configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder())
                    )
                    .build()
                )
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return webClient;
}
```

Implementation:

```
public ResponseObject getResponse(RequestObject request, String clientUrl) throws Exception {
    ResponseObject result = null;
    try {
        WebClient client = getWebClient(clientUrl);
        
        BodyInserter<RequestObject, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage> inserter = BodyInserters.fromValue(request);
        
        result = client.post().body(inserter).retrieve().bodyToMono(ResponseObject.class).block();
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Error:

```
2023-06-18 17:09:54.875| WARN|r.n.h.c.HttpClientConnect|[d243e7af-1, L:/R:xx.xx.xx.com] The connection observed an error

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=com.package.ResponseObject
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:392) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.writeWithMessageWriters(BodyInserters.java:382) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$fromValue$1(BodyInserters.java:98) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest.writeTo(DefaultClientRequestBuilder.java:272) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
```

I am expecting the WebClient to process "application/xml" content type in Spring boot 3 the same way as in Spring Boot 2.7.2

Comment: The dependencies you have for JAXB are for JavaEE not JakartaEE. When it doesn't detect the JakartaEE it won't be able to enable xml processing.

Comment: Hi  M. Deinum, Thank you for the response. I want to add some more information to the details posted earlier,  the application uses JAXB API form external backend integrations as a result we were trying balance the combination of JAXB and Jakarta jars for runtime to work. Please let me know if there are any suggestions/comments.

Comment: As stated you need Jakarta based JAXB implementation. If you have generated JAXB classes you need to regenerate those with the Jakarta version of JAXB. If you add the jaxb dependencies without a version you should get the correct ones.

Comment: Hey did  you make it work and found the right dependency replacements? I have jakarta.xml.bind, jakarta.xml.ws, jakarta.ws.rs, tried jackson-dataformat-xml, etc and still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot 2, `javax` import is used.

With Spring Boot 3, `jakarta` import is used.

If you use `javax` import with Spring Boot 3, there will be errors like yours. I had the same error message because I used `Apache CXF` to generate my java entities (from a XSD). The maven plugin generated entities with `javax.xml` import instead of `jakarta.xml` import.

In order to have the right import, I had to upgrade the maven plugin `org.apache.cxf.cxf-xjc-plugin` from `3.3.1` to `4.0.0`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <xsd>${basedir}/pathToXSD.xsd</xsd>
                                <packagename>mypackagename</packagename>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```